# JAXB: Unmarshal heterogeneous array

Tags: java, json, jaxb, unmarshalling, moxy

I'm trying to unmarshal using MOXy a json with the following structure:

```
[
  {
    "page": 1,
    "pages": 1
  },
  [
    {
        "indicator": {
            "id": "IC.BUS.EASE.XQ",
            "value": "Ease of doing business index"
        },
        "country": {
            "id": "1A",
            "value": "Arab World"
        },
        "value": "113.952380952381",
        "date": "2014"
    },
    ...
    ]
]
```

The first element of the array is an object and the second element is another array of complex elements. I've really searched here at SO and the MOXy documentation for a simmilar example without any success.

My best attempt at mapping the json document to JAVA classes is as follows. The root class is CountryDataResponse (getters & setters ommited):

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlType(propOrder ={"paginationInfo", "dataArray"})
public class CountryDataResponse {
    private DataArray dataArray;
    private PaginationInfo paginationInfo;
}
```

(I can see this is going to fail, because it isn't an array, but I'm completly lost.)

PaginationInfo class models the first element of the root array and DataArray class wraps the second element, which is an Array of Data class elements. Additionally, I've created the Indicator and Country classes for the complex types inside each Data element.

The main classes (Indicator and Country ommited):

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "paginationInfo")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class PaginationInfo {

    private int page;
    private int pages;
}
```

---

```
@XmlRootElement( name = "dataArray" )
public class DataArray {
    List<Data> datas;
}
```

---

```
@XmlRootElement(name="data")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Data {
    private Indicator indicator;
    private Country country;
    private String date;
    private double value;
}
```

Now, debugging the following code:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String test = "[{\"page\": 1,\"pages\": 1,\"per_page\": \"1000\",\"total\": 248},"
                + "["
                + "{\"indicator\": {\"id\": \"NY.GDP.MKTP.CD\",\"value\": \"GDP (current US$)\"},"
                + "\"country\": {\"id\": \"1A\",\"value\": \"Arab World\"},"
                + "\"value\": \"2853079422103.94\","
                + "\"decimal\": \"1\","
                + "\"date\": \"2013\"},"
                + "{\"indicator\": {\"id\": \"NY.GDP.MKTP.CD\",\"value\": \"GDP (current US$)\"},"
                + "\"country\": {\"id\": \"S3\",\"value\": \"Caribbean small states\"},"
                + "\"value\": \"67033118185.1864\","
                + "\"decimal\": \"1\","
                + "\"date\": \"2013\"}"
                + "]]";

    JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(CountryDataResponse.class, Country.class, Data.class, DataArray.class, Indicator.class, PaginationInfo.class);
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
    unmarshaller.setProperty(UnmarshallerProperties.MEDIA_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    unmarshaller.setProperty(UnmarshallerProperties.JSON_INCLUDE_ROOT, false);

    Object res = unmarshaller.unmarshal(json, CountryDataResponse.class);
}
```

The **res object** (of class JAXBElement) has a **value of type ArrayList**. The **first element** of the array **is** an object **of class CountryDataResponse** (it **should be PaginationInfo**), **the second** is another **ArrayList** with elements **of** class **CountryDataResponse**, too (they **should** **be** **Data** instances).

Can anyone help me, please, or it is simply a malformed json and it can't be automatically unmarshalled correctly?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to a MOXy's feature added in version 2.6, it's possible to unmarshal from javax.json.JsonStructure, javax.json.JsonObject and javax.json.JsonArray.

Using this feature I've managed to unmarshal the different parts of the original JSON to two objects: a PaginationInfo instance and an ArrayList of Data. These objects can then be used to configure an instance of CountryDataResponse, although it wouldn't be necessary as this class was created only to try to unmarshal directly from the JSON, in the first place.

```
public static CountryDataResponse javaSevenMode(String jsonString) 
    throws PropertyException, JAXBException {

    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = JAXB_CONTEXT.createUnmarshaller();
    unmarshaller.setProperty(UnmarshallerProperties.MEDIA_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    unmarshaller.setProperty(UnmarshallerProperties.JSON_INCLUDE_ROOT, false);

    StringReader sr = new StringReader(jsonString);
    JsonReader jsonReader = Json.createReader(sr);
    JsonArray rootArray = jsonReader.readArray();

    JsonObject paginationInfoJO = rootArray.getJsonObject(0);
    JsonStructureSource paginationInfoJSS = new JsonStructureSource(paginationInfoJO);
    PaginationInfo pi = unmarshaller.unmarshal(paginationInfoJSS, PaginationInfo.class).getValue();

    JsonArray dataJArray = rootArray.getJsonArray(1);
    JsonStructureSource dataArrayJSS = new JsonStructureSource(dataJArray);
    List<Data> datas
            = (List<Data>) unmarshaller.unmarshal(dataArrayJSS, Data.class)
            .getValue();

    DataArray da = new DataArray();
    da.setDatas(datas);

    CountryDataResponse cdr = new CountryDataResponse();
    cdr.setDataArray(da);
    cdr.setPaginationInfo(pi);

    return cdr;
}
```

Thanks to [@blaise-doughan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/383861/blaise-doughan) for inspiration (see http://blog.bdoughan.com/2013/07/eclipselink-moxy-and-java-api-for-json.html)

Answer (score 1):

Although the JSON is valid I would suggest changing the structure, something along the lines of:

```
{
"paginationInfo": {
    "page": 1,
    "pages": 1
},
"dataArray": [
    {
        "indicator": {
            "id": "IC.BUS.EASE.XQ",
            "value": "Ease of doing business index"
        },
        "country": {
            "id": "1A",
            "value": "Arab World"
        },
        "value": "113.952380952381",
        "date": "2014"
    }
]
```

}

This will allow you to extract the data you wish using the 'key' name which is how JSON is intended to be used.

Another approach would be to embed the data array within the paged object:

```
{
"page": 1,
"pages": 1,
"dataArray": [
    {
        "indicator": {
            "id": "IC.BUS.EASE.XQ",
            "value": "Ease of doing business index"
        },
        "country": {
            "id": "1A",
            "value": "Arab World"
        },
        "value": "113.952380952381",
        "date": "2014"
    }
]
```

}

This approach would allow you to create a generic page wrapper which could come in useful if you have multiple formats you would like to page.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Indeed your first suggestion is the result of marshalling a CountryDataResponse as it is now, so it would make a lot of sense to use it :) Unfortunately, I cannot change the structure: it's comming from http://api.worldbank.org/countries/indicators/NY.GDP.MKTP.CD?per_page=1000&MRV=1&format=json.

Comment: In that case I would look at creating a custom serializer for the CountryDataResponse object:

http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-custom-serialization